# How to send a value from input box (jade file) to scripting file(app.js)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

First I would like to point out that I am very new to Nodejs.
The problem I have is as following. 
I have a webpage in Jade and in the Jade file I have an inputbox link the code below

search.jade

```
input#phoneNumber(type='text', value='1st23-456-7890')
```

In the same file I have a piece of javascript  that converts it to a Json string

```
 script.
    var $items = $('#firstName, #lastName,#phoneNumber,#address ')
    var obj = {}
    $items.each(function() {
        obj[this.id] = $(this).val()
    })

    $('body').append('<br><pre>'+JSON.stringify(obj, null, ' '))
```

This string I would like to print in my search page and then pass it to my app.js file. Is this even possible and how do I achieve that. I was not able to print the result of the javascript in the jade page is that possible. I'm not sure what the problem is here can some one give me some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design a post api in nodejs using expressjs , and you can make ajax post call , Hope that will help you in this senario

Comment: is there a sitiuation where I don't need ajax

Comment: The problem is that the JSON result has to be send to a custom API

Comment: Any how we have to call the api from javascript right you do like below :function httpPost(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send({});//Send your Data
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

Comment: Where should I put this code in the jade file or the function in app,js